# GitHub security concern w/ new team members

Tags: github

I'm a small business owner. I run a small team of seven, and we create all our web tools in house. As we add to our team, I have concerns of security. My primary concern right now is that in order to add-on a new developer, I need to give them access to our frontend GitHub repository. This means they can download our entire website, even everybody's admin panels. They don't have access to our backend PHP files, but they do have access to everything else.

How can I add on a new team member without giving them the ability to download our code on their local drive? How can I protect our code from being stolen while still using GitHub?

Comment: At some point you are going to have to trust the people you hire. Do they sign NDA's? There are ways to protect yourself and still giving people the access that they will need to do their jobs.

Answer (score 1):

How do you want a developer to work on your code if he cannot download it? I believe if you have a development team which you elected you should be able to trust them so there should not be any concern about security. In the end you give them access to **code** and **not do data**.
Also should you not have any secrets/passwords or similar in your code, so no worries there neither.
I believe more important is that you have code reviews, static code analysis etc. in place so that you ensure your code is safe and secure.
When using git also think about your branching strategy and which branch contains your releasable code. Protect these branches so only the ones you want can merge code into it. Ensure no-one can add code directly to this branch(es)

Comment: Note that the `.gitignore` file can be used to protect secreds from version control.

Comment: Can you share a link with more details, that may be interesting for the ones reading this. However to my understanding `.gitignore` can help you to keep files from being added to source control, however it does not prohibits code do be hard-coded into your source. This however can be mitigated using source code analysis and code review

Comment: I mean, that you can put sensitive data in another file/directory and blacklist it in the `.gitignore` file.

Comment: I agree. We should trust the people we hire. However, to give a physical example when we hire someone new we typically don't give them the keys to the facility or the safe on the first day. Typically these responsibilities are earned over time. My concern, if someone is relieved of their position, and they would take that code and try to pass it on as their own. I think this would cause some negative SEO results and other damages. All our team members are remote, and some live in different countries.

Comment: A counter example: if you hire a company to secure your facility e.g. during night, you probably will hand them the keys as otherwise how they can check inside the building. You do this cause you trust them to do their job.

I guess there is no 100% guarantee that you can prevent somebody taking your code if there is enough bad energy - just take Snowden as an example. And he was not working Remote but physically in the same place... And code in the end is text, you just can take a picture if you cannot download it.

As @Z4-Tier mentioned in one of the comments, use NDA's.